Playload CMS how to use endpoint without authentication?
I have headless cms Payload and want to display a list of posts. But looks like it requests cookie authentication. I have found the disableLocalStrategy flag but It does not work I'm making postman request and getting the "You are not allowed to perform this action." error.
const Posts: CollectionConfig = {
  slug: "posts",
  auth: {
    disableLocalStrategy: true,
  },
  admin: {
    defaultColumns: ["title", "text"],
  },
  fields: [...],
}```

Any ideas how to fix this?


I have found the solution by adding access: { read?: Access} so here is my hack
const Posts: CollectionConfig = {
  slug: "posts",
  access: {
    read: () => true,
  },
  admin: {...},
  fields: [...],
} 

